# MongoDB make drop removeall commands unworkable?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any setting in MongoDB config file by which on my database or Collection no operation like `DROP` `collection` OR `Database`, OR `db.collections.remove({})`, OR **any operation which remove more than one records at a time** unworkable?

And if it isn't possible directly than what other ways you people use in order to not accidentally remove your data from the database?

Or is there any built-in way in MongoDB to put deleted records in a disk which would get flushed after a particular amount of time, in order to get the deleted data back within a time period?

Thank you

Comment: You mean ["permissions"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/). If you don't give a user account ( i.e what your application uses to connect ) permission to do things, then it cannot do them. [`dropCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#dropCollection) for example is just one of possible privilege actions. [`readWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite) as a role includes actions, but you can make a role with only actions you want. Totally customizable.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for mentioning, but what about comands like `db.collections.remove({})` ?

Comment: "Actions". Everything is an "action". So read the documentation and define a role with only the "actions" you want to give.

Comment: @NeilLunn Ok I will read the docs, also what about `Or is there any built-in way in MongoDB to put deleted records in a disk which would get flushed after a particular amount of time, in order to get the deleted data back within a time period?`

Comment: What would not be "built in" about a complete permissions and actions system? Sounds "built in" to me. You're asking how to "restrict access to certain actions", which is the same general question with the same general answer.

Comment: Enabling authentication and configuring appropriate user roles is a good starting point: a read-only only user won't accidentally remove data. For short term data recovery you can configure a [delayed replica set member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/) which applies operations from the source oplog after a configurable period of time, but the more general solution is to implement a [backup strategy](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) that meets your requirements.